# App crash issue in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We are developing app to list available ebooks using Xamarin Forms. The ebook collections are taken from API and store it in local DB. If we access local database to get stored collections the app getting crashed in device. But it works fine in simulator in iOS and android devices. We are getting below error in output window.

**Error Details:**

> Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/4a279c9a/source/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4714, condition `array->len == 1' not met

**Machine Details:**

- Operating System - Mac OS X 10.12.4
- Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac - Version 7.1 (build 1297)
- Xamarin.Profiler - Version: 1.5.5
- Apple Developer Tools - Xcode 8.3.2 (12175) (Build 8E2002)
- Xamarin.iOS - Version: 10.12.0.18 (Visual Studio Community)
- Xamarin.Mac - Version: 3.6.0.17 (Visual Studio Community)

What could be the reason for this issue? Is this issue from Xamarin? If yes, suggest work around to resolve this issue. Please help on this?

Regards,

Cheran T

Answer (score 1):

That Xamarin related problem, you can read more here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96564/sigabrt-while-debugging-async-methods#latest

There is no official solution from Xamarin, but some people report that if they add

`Task.Delay(*some time*)`

after the awaited method inside the async function (the request for collection in your case) the problem goes away. It's not a valid fix in any case, but since there is no actions from Xamarin, it's better than nothing.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, on Android, VS2017 Community, if I hit F10 or F11 after an async operation, the app crashes. I must one of the few poor bastards seeing this as there is no fix anywhere for android.